# ? How to obtain tags by part of element name

Tags: xmldocument, getelementsbytagname

I have the following XML response:

```
<S:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns0:RespOpReportGen
            xmlns:ns7="http://my.service.url/Schemas/folder1"
            xmlns:ns4="http://my.service.url/framework/folder2"
            xmlns:ns13="http://my.service.url/framework/folder3"
            xmlns:ns0="http://my.service.url/framework/folder4">
         <ns0:contextResponse>
            <ns4:trnResult>
               <ns13:trnStatus/>
               <ns13:OKNOResponse>B</ns13:OKNOResponse>
               <ns13:ApprovalNr>0</ns13:ApprovalNr>
               <ns13:trnID>213454567</ns13:trnID>
               <ns13:trnDate>2019-03-13T13:02:10.76</ns13:trnDate>
            </ns4:trnResult>
         </ns0:contextResponse>
         <ns0:FileResponse>
            <ns7:contentFile>JVBERi0</ns7:contentFile>
            <ns7:mimeType>application/pdf</ns7:mimeType>
         </ns0:FileResponse>
      </ns0:RespOpReportGen>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I use the following code in order to obtain the value in tag **ns7:contentFile**

```
Dim soapResultXml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
soapResultXml.LoadXml(soapResult)

Dim resultado As XmlNodeList = soapResultXml.GetElementsByTagName("contentFile")
```

... but i got no results.

Is there a way to obtain the tags by part of the name? or ... how can i obtain "ns7:" value to concatenate it with "contentFile" ?

Thanks in advance, and best regards.

**EDIT**

> ```
> Dim soapResultXml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
> soapResultXml.LoadXml(soapResult)
> Dim resultado As XmlNodeList = soapResultXml.SelectNodes("//*[contains(name(),'contentFile')]")
> ```

It works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add and configure `XmlNamespaceManager`. Something like this.

```
Dim soapResultXml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
soapResultXml.LoadXml(soapResult)

Dim xnm as New XmlNamespaceManager(soapResultXml.NameTable)
xnm.AddNamespace("ns7", "http://my.service.url/folder1")

''//add more namespaces
''// xnm.AddNamespace("ns8", "http://my.service.url/folder2")
''//prefix doesn't matter. URI matters.

Dim resultado As XmlNodeList = soapResultXml.SelectNodes("contentFile", xnm)
```

Comment: i noticed not always the tag "contentFile" is preceeded by "ns7:" ... it could be "ns14:", "ns9:", ...

Comment: Add more namespaces to `xnm`